# How can I check if a string contains a number between two brackets and return the location?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, parsing

Say I have `str = "qwop(8) 5"` and I want to return the position of 8.

I have the following solution:

```
import re

str = "qwop(8) 5"
regex = re.compile("\(\d\)")
match = re.search(regex, string) # match object has span = (4, 7)
print(match.span()[0] + 1)       # +1 gets at the number 8 rather than the first bracket
```

This seems really messy. Is there a more sophisticated solution? Preferably using `re` as I've already imported that for other uses.

Comment: Sure, use capturing groups. [`re.compile("\((\d)\)")` -> `.group(1)`](https://ideone.com/BKY3BC).

Comment: @DmytroChekunov because he doesn't know *a priori* **what** number it is, only that it is in parentheses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `match.start()` to get the start index of the match, and a capturing group to capture specifically the digit between the brackets to avoid the `+1` in the index. If you want the very start of the pattern, use `match.start()`, if you only want the digit, use `match.start(1)`;

```
import re
test_str = 'qwop(8) 5'
pattern = r'\((\d)\)'
match = re.search(pattern, test_str)

start_index = match.start()
print('Start index:\t{}\nCharacter at index:\t{}'.format(start_index,
                                                         test_str[start_index]))
match_index = match.start(1)
print('Match index:\t{}\nCharacter at index:\t{}'.format(match_index,
                                                         test_str[match_index]))
```

Outputs;

```
Start index:    4
Character at index: (
Match index:    5
Character at index: 8
```

Comment: It is also usually unnecessary to compile a regex prior to use.

Comment: Thanks @Błotosmętek, I had just copied and pasted OP's answer and made the necessary changes. I've introduced a few adjustments now.

Comment: Oh, and you should add 1 to get position of the digit rather than the bracket.

Comment: Thanks, what does the r do in `pattern = r'\(\d\)'`?

Comment: It just tells python that it's a regex string

Comment: @TomWyllie: no it tells Python that it is a *raw* string. There is no such thing as a *regex* string. It will simply not *escape* the string. So `\n` is a string with two chars, not one new line.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem. What I of course meant was *in this use case, it tells python to treat this string as though it is regex.*

Comment: @TomWyllie No, that is still incorrect.  A raw string means that no extra escapes are needed to write (for example) a literal `\n` - compare `r'\n'` to `'\\n`'.  In no way does prepending the `r` tell python to treat the string as though it is a regex. It is pure coincidence that a) both "raw" and "regex" begin with "r" and b) the most common use case for raw strings is in the context of regex. If I do `pattern = r'\(\d\); regex = re.compile(pattern)`, only at the second line when a function from the `re` module is invoked that python "knows" the pattern is a regular expression.

Comment: @TomWyllie While trying to simplify things is noble, I have seen many misunderstandings on this site due to people being given an overly simple explanation of an issue which then becomes the foundation of a completely incorrect understanding of a concept.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\((\d+)\)')
```

The `r` prefix means that we are working with a *raw* string. A raw string means that if you write for instance `r'\n'`, Python will *not* interpret this as a string with a new line character. But as a string with two characters: a backslash (`'\\'`) and an `'n'`.

The additional brackets are there to define a capture group. Furthermore a number is a sequence of (one or more) digits. So the `+` makes sure that we will capture `(1425)` as well.

We can then perform a `.search()` and obtain a match. You then can use `.start(1)` to obtain the *start* of the *first* capture group:

```
>>> regex.search(data)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 7), match='(8)'>
>>> regex.search(data).start(1)
5
```

If you are inteested in the content of the first capture group, you can call `.group(1)`:

```
>>> regex.search(data).group(1)
'8'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

s = "qwop(8)(9) 5"
regex = re.compile("\(\d\)")
match = re.search(regex, s)
print(match.start() + 1)
```

start() means the start index, re.search search for the first occurrence.
so this will only show the index of (8).

Comment: Can you explain **why** this solves the issue instead of just posting some code? This will be far more helpful, especially for beginners, thanks.